# Unable to copy new Google Form submission data to new sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm attempting to copy new form submission data in a Google Sheet database into a different sheet, in the same file. My code copies new data entered by me directly on the database sheet, however it refuses to copy data input by the Google Form. I am using a Google Script for this action. Below is my code.

I ran into an issue where I can't **cut** the database info because it is protected by the form. Is this why I also can't copy and paste it into a new sheet with a script? Thanks for your help everyone.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named main
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Website Form Contacts") { //&& r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == true
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Initial Lead Contact");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    // s.getRange(row, numColumns + 1).setValue(false);
    s.deleteRow(row, 8);

  } else if(s.getName() == "Initial Lead Contact" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Website Form Contacts");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### `onEdit` trigger only fires when data edits are made by a human

> If you want the trigger to fire on every new form submission, you need
>   to use the [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onFormSubmit` trigger.

You could rewrite your function as following, using the available [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) for `Form submit` and bind the `onFormSubmit` trigger to the function:

```
function myFunction(event) {
  var r = event.range;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if(s.getName() == "Website Form Contacts") {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Initial Lead Contact");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Initial Lead Contact" /*&& r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == false*/) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Website Form Contacts");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  }
 r.copyTo(target);
}
```

Keep in mind:

- You cannot use `event.source` as a `formSubmit` event object
- The conditions `r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == false` are unlikely to be fulfilled on formSubmit
- Form submission often creates new sheets with new names, so your conditions `if(s.getName() == ...` might not be fulfilled

If you want your function to work both `onEdit` and `onFormSubmit`, you can keep calling it `onEdit` and leave largely as it is.

Just bind the installable `onFormSubmit` trigger and remove the parts that are not supported `onFormSubmit` (e.g. `event.source`) and make sure that the condition for the sheet name is fulfillable.

Do replace `event.source.getActiveRange();` by `event.range` which is supported by both`onEdit` and `onFormSubmit` triggers.